# The non-generic type 'DelegateCommand' cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

```
 public ICommand OpenDialogFile
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand<RichEditBox>(OpenDialogToAttach);
            }
        }

Command="{Binding OpenDialogFile}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TweetEditBox}"
```

So, DeledateCommand doest understand about RichEditBox. While I use "

> OpenDialogToAttach(RichEditBox editBox)".

How to solve it?. I dev on UWP.

Here is a DelegateCommand Code.Initializes a new instance of the DelegateCommand class that

```
 internal class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;

    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the RelayCommand class that 
    /// can always execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">If the execute argument is null.</exception>
    public DelegateCommand(Action execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the RelayCommand class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">If the execute argument is null.</exception>
    public DelegateCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when changes occur that affect whether the command should execute.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="CanExecuteChanged" /> event.
    /// </summary>
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1030:UseEventsWhereAppropriate",
        Justification = "This cannot be an event")]
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">This parameter will always be ignored.</param>
    /// <returns>true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.</returns>
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">This parameter will always be ignored.</param>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            _execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which DelegateCommand are you using? sho your import statements

Comment: ` public DelegateCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            }

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }`

Comment: you are showing me a constructor, not using statement. So this is your class... the you have to add its body to a question. I dont think your class is generic

Comment: Updated Source.

Comment: well its not Generic class, why are you trying to instantiate it with type parameter and what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: what happens when you remove <RichEditBox> part?

Comment: I want to pass a RichEditBox to a object
private async void OpenDialogToAttach(RichEditBox tweetEditBox)
        {
            FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();

Comment: No problem but it don't pass data to OpenDialogToAttach

Comment: When I remove <RichEditBox> -> can't convert method group to Action

Comment: so what is OpenDialogToAttach

Comment: you need to pass an Action to DelegateCOmmand, just do `new DelegateCommand( () => { capture your edit box and whatever you need here} );`

Comment: It's a object. I use it to open window and pick files from windows.

void OpenDialogToAttach(....)

Comment: Can you talk clearly?

Comment: So its me who is not talking clearly here ?) okay..

Comment: You can give a example. I don't understand at new DelegateCommand( () => { capture your edit box and whatever you need here} );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `DelegateCommand` is not generic so you can't instantiate it with type parameter `RichEditBox` like you are trying to.

You have a constructor that accepts action so you can conveniently pass lambda to it capturing context you need, for instance:

```
return new DelegateCommand(x => {
    RichEditBox richBox = (RichEditBox) x;
    OpenDialogToAttach()...
});
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, Ive noticed that it accepts Action and not Action<T> so you cant have parameters.

Comment: Do you have instance of your RichEditBox in your code ? If yes then you dont need to pass anything

Comment: The idea would be that the implementation of the `DelegateCommand` is in the viewmodel. And there you have no reverences to view components.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of the `DelegateCommand` class you are using doesn't support the generic argument you are trying to pass to it.

```
return new DelegateCommand<RichEditBox>(OpenDialogToAttach)
```

You could use the implementation of the `DelegateCommand` class from [`Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654132.aspx). It's an implementation with an generic argument.

Comment: It come from nugget or where is it?Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Commands.

Comment: [This](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Core/6.3.0-pre1) is the core nuget package. I dont know if this is the same implementation as in the microsoft package. Maybe you need also [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Wpf/6.3.0-pre1) package.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the Prism implementation of the generic DelegateCommand class for UWP on GitHub: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Commands/DelegateCommand%7BT%7D.cs.

You could replace your own implementation with this one, i.e. copy the class definition into your project. You will also need the base class: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Commands/DelegateCommandBase.cs

Alternatively you can install the Prism.Windows package using NuGet (Tools->Nuget Package Manager->Package Manager Console in Visual Studio): https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Windows/

...and use the DelegateCommand in your code directly:

```
public ICommand OpenDialogFile
    {
        get
        {
            return new Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand<RichEditBox>(OpenDialogToAttach);
        }
    }
```